# SQL 2 table odd filter required (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa-2.0

I'm using jpa and need to figure out this oddball filter i need with just 2 tables.

Description:

Find the rows with a distinct rte, cd combination with the smallest id (this would be row 1, 4, and 6).  Now join these rows with Table 2 (fkey-pkey) in order to filter on the country.  If a match, return all the rows in table 1 with that distinct rte, cd combination.

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc932/7

```
        Table 1

id       rte      cd     fkey
---      ----     ---    ----
1        A         E      21
2        A         E      24
3        A         E      24
4        B         W      24
5        B         W      21
6        C         E      21
7        C         E      30


        Table 2

pkey    country
----    -------
 21       US
 24       MX
 30       CA
```

If I filter on US, the result would be:

```
id       rte      cd     fkey
---      ----     ---    ----
1        A         E      21
2        A         E      24
3        A         E      24
6        C         E      21
7        C         E      30
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Oracle, updated title.

Comment: If you filter US how come your result have fkey (24, 30) ?

Comment: Carlos, did you read the process i put above?

Comment: Yes I did, Maybe you think was clear, but isn't. You should read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've updated my description, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH a AS (SELECT rte, cd, max(fkey) keep (dense_rank first order by id asc) first_fkey
FROM   table_1
GROUP BY rte, cd )
SELECT 
FROM a INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.pkey = a.first_fkey
INNER JOIN table_1 on table_1.rte = a.rte and table_1.cd = a.cd
WHERE table_2.country = 'US'
```

Syntax not checked for typos, but the idea should work.  Get the fkey of the row in each rte/cd having the lowest ID.  Then, join to country.  Then join back to get the rest of the rows from table 1.

### Alternate version - no WITH or DENSE_RANK

```
SELECT t1b.id, t1b.rte, t1b.cd, t1b.fkey
FROM table1 t1a,
     table2 t2,
     table1 t1b
WHERE t2.pkey = t1a.fkey
AND   t1b.rte = t1a.rte
and   t1b.cd = t1a.cd
and not exists ( SELECT 'x' FROM table1 t1c WHERE t1c.rte = t1a.rte and t1c.cd = t1a.cd and t1c.id < t1a.id )
and t2.country = 'US'
```

If JPA doesn't even support `NOT EXISTS`, try to create the query as a database view and give the view to JPA.

Also, the WITH/DENSE_RANK version would run faster, so that's the one to use if you go the view-route.

Comment: I don't think jpa supports WITH, dense_rank, etc.

Comment: I've added a rough sqlfiddle in the description that retrieves the correct data, but I don't think jpa supports multiple column IN clauses...ugh.

Comment: You cannot wrap that SQL in a view and use the view in JPA?